# Binary Search using Recursion in java

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search

I am writing a program for a recursive binary search. I have an input file with a series of sorted numbers, which I added to an ArrayList. The program searches to see if a key given by user input is in the ArrayList.

```
public static int binarySearch(int key, int median){
    if(key == (int)array.get(median)){
        return key;
    }else if(key < (int)array.get(median)){
        binarySearch(key,median-1);
    }else if(key > (int)array.get(median)){
        binarySearch(key,median+1);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

For example, let's say the key is 90. I debugged and placed watches at key and array.get(median). After stepping through the program, I discovered that even when key and array.get(median) are equal to 90, the program continues through the loop without ever returning the key. I know that recursion isn't ideal for this, but it's what I need to use.

Comment: This looks wrong. For starters, a binary search method receives _three_ parameters: the key, the lower index and the upper index. See an [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Recursive)

Comment: Simulate with pencil and paper what the program is doing for some small input. There are several problems in the code. You will profit the most if you find them yourself.

Answer (score 2):

This does not look like a correct binary search, as a binary search uses a divide and conquer approach. You only divide your list initially once and then check every element from there on. It would be better to then just divide your list again and so on, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Anyway, to get your code running, why you do not get an result is most likely because you do not return the result of the recursion, but instead -1.

Remove the return -1 and set a return before your recursive binarySearch calls. And you are missing a exit condition when you do not find the element.

Example (still not a correct binary search):

```
public static int binarySearch(int key, int median){
    if (median < 0 || median > array.size() - 1) { // element not found
        return -1;
    }
    if (key == (int)array.get(median)){
        return key;
    } else if(key < (int)array.get(median)){
        return binarySearch(key,median-1);
    } else{
        return binarySearch(key,median+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: okay, thank you. That fixed the issue. It just gives me an error, if the index is not found, which I assume is the reason that I need to include low and high as parameters instead of middle. I just have one question. Why do you say to remove the return -1? I need a return there, and it doesn't seem to be causing any issues.

Comment: Nope, if it is equal you return, if it is bigger you return and if it is smaller you return. One of these criteria is always met so you do not need the return -1

Comment: Java still requires the method to return something outside of the loop, or at least that's the error it gives me if i remove it.

Comment: What loop? You are using recursion. If it finds the element it returns the key. Otherwise it searches on (goes into the next recursion) and returns that result. Still, what you are missing is a exit condition when the element is not found, but that is it. But you do not need the return -1 down there as this code could never be reached.

Comment: @Tim Still can't remove the last `return -1` (loop or not) without other changes, because not all code paths return a value. The Java compiler has minimal static analysis (it *won't* analyze `a==b|a<b|a>b` as complete, even when a and b are immutable).

Comment: Ah, I see, then just replace the last else if by just else, no need to keep code that can never be reached ;)

Comment: @Tim Edit the answer (with relevant code) - all that information is lost down here!

Comment: @Tim Ah, I missed that the `if` was removed.

Answer (score 1):

If all you care about is whether it is in the data structure...

```
public static boolean binarySearch(int key, int median){

    if(key == (int)array.get(median)){
        return true;
    }else if(key < (int)array.get(median)){
        return binarySearch(key,median-1);
    }else if(key > (int)array.get(median)){
        return binarySearch(key,median+1);
    }
}
```

your code could be better written, but copied to to get across the important part of it

Answer (score 1):

You should change your code like this:

```
public static int binarySearch(int key, int median){
if(key == (int)array.get(median)){
    return key;
}else if(key < (int)array.get(median)){
    return binarySearch(key,median-1);
}else if(key > (int)array.get(median)){
    return binarySearch(key,median+1);
}
return -1;
}
```

If you do this your recursion would end but I will leave it to you to test out your binary search code. There are some things like the start index and the end index that you are ignoring in this method The return statements should be added because if you don't the control moves to the next statement in the method which is undesirable. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

The code posted is *not* a [Binary Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) and is, in fact, a Linear Search using recursion. A Binary Search *divides the  search space in half* each step, binary meaning "two halves" in context. The result is that this Linear Search runs in O(n) and not the expected O(lg n) bounds of a Binary Search

Problems/issues (other than it *not* being a Binary Search):

- The values from the recursive cases are *lost* as they are not themselves returned. The result of a recursive case *must* be used in some way (or why call the function at all?). In this case the value should be returned directly, eg. `return binarySearch(..)`. This causes "continues through the loop without ever returning the key" - it actually *does* find the key, but discards the recursive result.
- The code does not correctly detect the out-of-bounds terminal condition. This may result in an IndexOutOfBoundsException when the key is not found.
- The step-left/right approach might never terminate correctly without further logic. For example, when the list is {1,3,5,7} and the value being sought is 4 the original code will ping-pong between indices 1 (value 3) and 2 (value 4). This will result in a StackOverflowError being thrown.
- The key is returned. This makes little sense as the key is already known and it also prevents -1 from being detectable. Return the *index* found instead, or a boolean if only an existence test is required.

Take some time to understand and fix these issues .. and then read on for a spoiler if needed.

---

Consider this rewrite fixing the issues outlined above. Note that it is *overly complex*<sup>1</sup> while still employing an inferior algorithm and O(n) performance. In any case;

```
// By taking in the List we make this function universal and not
// dependent upon a static field. It should probably take in a List<Integer>
// but I don't know what the actual type of "array" is. A more advanced
// implementation would take in List<Comparable> and then be modified to work
// with any objects that correctly implement said interface.
public static int linearSearch(int key, List list, int index, int step) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= list.size()) {
       // Base case: not found, out of bounds
       return -1;
    }

    int x = (int)list.get(index);
    if (key < x && step <= 0) {       // need to look left, NOT looking right
        // Recursive case: look left, returning result
        return linearSearch(key, list, index - 1, -1);
    } else if (key > x && step >= 0){ // need to look right, NOT looking left
        // Recursive case: look right, returning result
        return linearSearch(key, list, index + 1, +1);
    } else if (key == x) {
        // Base case: found key, return index found
        return index;  
    } else {
        // Base case: key not equal, refusing to ping-pong
        return -1;
    }
}
```

And then consider the use of this helper/wrapper function;

```
// Returns the index in "array" where key was found, or -1 if it was not found
public static int linearSearch(int key) {
    // Have to start somewhere, might as well be the middle..
    // ..but it does NOT make the time complexity any better
    // ..and it is still NOT a Binary Search.
    return linearSearch(key, array, array.size() / 2, 0);
}
```

<sup>1</sup> Alternatively, since it *is* a Linear Search it could be rewritten without the extra left/right movement and have the *same* complexity bounds. (It is also trivial to modify this simpler code to a [recursive Binary Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Recursive).)

```
public static int linearSearch(int key, List list, int index) {
    if (index >= list.size() {
        // Base case: end of list
        return -1;
    }

    int x = (int)list.get(index);
    if (key < x) {
        // Recursive case: not there yet, keep looking
        return linearSearch(key, list, index + 1);
    } else if (key == x) {
        // Base case: found key, return index
        return index;
    } else { // -> key > x
        // Base case: read past where the key would be found
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's binary search for `ArrayList<Integer>` :)

```
public int binarySearch(List<Integer> list, int find) {
    int mid = list.size() / 2;
    int val = list.get(mid);

    if (val == find) {
        return val;
    } else if (list.size() == 1) {
        return -1;
    }

    return val > find ?
        binarySearch(list.subList(0, mid), find) :
        binarySearch(list.subList(mid, list.size()), find);
}
```

Comment: The question is 2 years old.